# PostgreSQL where clause not pushed down when using grouping sets

Tags: sql, postgresql, set, grouping

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
        product_location_id,
        location_bin_id,
        product_lot_id,
        product_serial_id,
        CASE
            WHEN GROUPING (product_location_id, location_bin_id, product_lot_id, product_serial_id) = 0 AND product_serial_id IS NOT NULL THEN
                'Serial'
            WHEN GROUPING (product_location_id, location_bin_id, product_lot_id, product_serial_id) = 0 THEN
                'Lot'
            ELSE
                'Quantity'
        END AS pick_by
    FROM product_location_bins
    WHERE status != 'Void'
        AND has_quantity = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
        (product_location_id, location_bin_id, product_lot_id, product_serial_id),
        (product_location_id, location_bin_id)
      )
    HAVING SUM(quantity) > 0
) x
WHERE x.product_serial_id = 5643
```

I have the above query.  Using a normal GROUP BY postgres is able to "push down" the outer where clause and use the index on product_serial_id.  When I use grouping sets it's unable to do so.  It resolves the entire inner query and then filters the results.  I'm wondering why this is.  Is it a limitation with grouping sets?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is odd.  Your outer `where` clause eliminates the second set of results from `grouping sets`, because `product_serial_id` would be `NULL` for the second set.  This gets filtered out in the outer `where`.

I think you want something like this for the outer query:

```
WHERE x.product_serial_id = 5643 OR x.product_serial_id IS NULL
```

I suppose that Postgres could add optimizations for poorly written code -- that is, eliminate the work for the second `grouping sets` set because it is filtered out by the outer `where`.  However, that is not usually the focus of optimizations.

Comment: The where clause can be any of the columns in either of the grouping sets and is appended dynamically.  My question would be the same if it was WHERE x.product_location_id = 123... the where clause isn't pushed down for that either.